# Copy info from one dynamically created user control to another dynamically created user control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls, copy

My ASP.NET WebForm has a place holder on it and user controls are dynamically added to it.  The controls mostly have textboxes.  Sometimes there are two user controls, sometimes there are ten.  Everything is working as expected.  My question is about how to implement a new feature.

My customer has a new request to copy data from the first control to another control checking a checkbox associated with the additional control in question.

At first, this sounded easy...  Add a checkbox to the placeholder for each user control and then write some JavaScript to copy the data from the first control to the additional control.  Then I realized that by those textboxes being in a user control, I don't really have access to modify the HTML inputs directly.

Next I started thinking about adding checkboxes that will automatically post back, but how do I go about dynamically adding a checkbox to a placeholder, and then come up with a way to add event handler to the checkbox and pass in the information necessary to loop through the controls and copy the values.  This approach seems way too complicated with too much overhead to accomplish my goal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have JavaScript as a tag but don't mention it in your question... is using it out of the question?

Comment: JavaScript is perfectly acceptable and probably preferred. I think that the fact that the textboxes are in a user control makes it a bit cumbersome to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that since the checkboxes are in a user control, you don't have access to them.

Could you expose the ClientIDs using a property of the user control and then work with them in javascript? Something like this:

```
user_control {
   int checkboxId { get { return checkbox.ClientId; } }
}
```

If you have more code that would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late to help you, but just so another answer is out there...
Including the checkbox as a part of the user control simplifies the issue considerably.

I had a similar situation, with maybe 10-15 UI controls in a user control, with a checkbox associated with the first one which, when checked, meant that I should copy the info from the first user control to all of the others.

Since it was all built in the codebehind, I simply exposed a boolean property of the user control named `ShowCheckBox`, which toggled the visibility of the checkbox.  I set this to true in the first one, and false in all of the others.  Thus, I knew that the event could only be raised by a click of the first user control's checkbox.  Then, in the event handler for the checkbox, I handled the copying from the first user control to all of the others. (By the way, be sure to set `AutoPostBack=true` on that checkbox or you'll wonder why the event isn't firing.)

Javascript would definitely provide a better user experience, but this worked for me and didn't require me to figure out how to get the ClientId values into the javascript.  (Although that's exactly what I need to do now, which is how I stumbled upon this question.  :-)  )